# Laravel Webpack error on npm run watch

Tags: laravel, webpack

I've got problem with laravel webpack. It was working without problems, since today:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string] | function
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration.entry['/js/creative'] should be a string.
      -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry['/js/creative'] should not contain the item 'C:\xampp\htdocs\petsland2\resources\assets\js\creative.js' twice.
    * configuration.entry should be a string.
      -> An entry point without name. The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry should be an array:
      [non-empty string]
    * configuration.entry should be an instance of function
      -> A Function returning an entry object, an entry string, an entry array or a promise to these things.
```

I reloaded configruation to default, but it isn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show us your webpack.mix.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you are using `creative.js` twice as entry point.

Comment: Yeah... it's wieird, I've got copy of every line in mix file. Thanks